# Identification of Datastage latest modified jobs

Tags: datastage

How to identify the jobs which are modified today in datastage 8.1.
Thanks 
Raghu

Answer (score 4):

Programmatically or by hand?

As of 8.x at least there is a Tools->Advanced find that lets you search by modification date including "Today".

Answer (score 3):

my environment: rhel4 ds8.1 reposity metadata:db2

the below code is usually used:

```
 - select
   (timestamp('01/01/1970','00:00:00')+(xmeta_creation_timestamp_xmeta/1000)
   seconds) as
   creation_time,(timestamp('01/01/1970','00:00:00')+(xmetamodificationtimestampxmet/1000)
   seconds) as modified_time,a.*
       from 
       xmeta.datastagex_xmetagen_dsjobdefc2e76d84 as a
       where name_xmeta=dsjob_name
```

you can change the where condition to obtain the modified today job infomation.

```
 - where
   to_char((timestamp('01/01/1970','00:00:00')+(xmetamodificationtimestampxmet/1000)
   seconds),'YYYYMMDD') = to_char(current timestamp,'YYYYMMDD');
```

Comment: Even though this use of XMETA is unsupported, I agree this is the best method of collecting recent modifications into a usable format.

Answer (score 0):

Infosphere Information Server Manager will give you a nice GUI interface where you can go to the code in question ; it will tell you the the create date , the last modifying date and the create user and last modifying user.